# Highcharts IE8 stacked column series color is transparent

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am using Highcharts v3.0.1. The chart has multiple series including spline and stacked column. For some reason the colors of stacked column chart is hidden/tranparent in IE8 and working fine in all other browsers. 
IE8 [image: IE8]

FF
[image]

Options variable is defined as

```
optionsChart= {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'divChart',
            zoomType: 'xy',
            reflow: false,
            resetZoomButton: {
                position: {
                    align: 'left', // by default right
                    x: 0,
                    y: -30
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'WindBOOST'
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories:  UPGRADES.WB_WIND_SPEED,
            tickInterval: 4,
            title: {
                enabled: true,
                text: 'Wind Speed (m/s)'
            }
        },
        yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0) +'';
                },
                style: {
                    color: '#89A54E'
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Power (KW)',
                style: {
                    color: '#89A54E'
                }
            },
            min:0
        }, { // Secondary yAxis
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Site Level Production (MWh)',
                style: {
                    color: '#4572A7'
                }
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value +'';
                },
                style: {
                    color: '#4572A7'
                }
            },
            min:0,
            opposite: true
        }],
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
             column: {
                 stacking: 'normal'
             },
            series: {
                marker: {
                    fillColor: 'none',
                    lineColor: null
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            itemHiddenStyle: {
                color: '#666060',
                fontSize: '10px'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Site Power Curve',
            color: '#E04023',
            type: 'spline',
            data: []
        }, {
            name: 'WindBOOST',
            color: '#89A54E',
            type: 'spline',
            data: []
        },{
            color: '#910000',
            name: 'Stacked',
            type: 'column',
            yAxis: 1,
            data: []
        },{
            name: 'IEC TCII',
            color: '#4572A7',
            type: 'column',
            yAxis: 1,
            data: []
        }]
};
```

and later populating the data values dynamically

```
 optionsChart.series[1].name = "WindBOOST Power Curve";
     optionsChart.series[2].name = "WindBOOST";
     optionsChart.series[3].name = "Baseline";


     optionsChart.series[3].data = UPGRADES.WEIBULL_BASELINE;
     optionsChart.series[2].data = UPGRADES.WEIBULL_UPGRADED;

     optionsChart.chart.renderTo ="divChartWindBOOST";

    chartComparison = new Highcharts.Chart(optionsChart);
    chartComparison.setTitle({text: "WindBOOST"});
```

Any idea?

Comment: It is possible to reproduce your example in the jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Go to http://www.gerenewablesupgrades.com/ select WindBOOST and enter values and hit calculate

Comment: You have many scripts / plugins so it is quite diffuicult ot debugging, will be more helpful if you recreate your example with sample data in fiddle. Morever some of plugins like select also doens't work, so I'm not sure if it is not related with your issue. Please try to set pointWidht http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointWidth

Comment: pointWidth worked like a charm!. Thanks Sebastian